# How to change Bootstrap expect of consul server without restarting?

Tags: docker, consul

How can I change the `bootstrap-expect` of a consul server without bringing it down?

(Isn't that possible?)

**Add:**
My Consul is running in a Docker container.
Due to a lot key/value updates in the consul, I can't afford to lose the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you set bootstap-expect in a config file, a `consul reload` or SIGHUP should do the trick.  If you set it on the command line, I don't believe you can.

But restarting consul shouldn't be a big thing, even in production, assuming you already have more than 1 server.

Comment: How do I do the same in a docker container?
Where will I find the config-file?

Comment: look at the `Dockerfile` for the image you are running, it should show you what the command line is for consul, and that will have either a `-config-file=` or `-config-dir=` option mentioning where that Docker image hid it's config file(s). This is just standard Docker mess.  Sometimes it's well documented, but I wouldn't count on it :)

Comment: There is no `config-dir` specified. I figured out the `data` directory. But it doesn't have any configuration file.

Comment: then bootstap-expect must have been specified on the command line, and you wouldn't be able to change that without a restart.  but you really shouldn't need to change it, like ever.  you say I'm going to have X consul servers, and go for it.  You do not need to change it per consul agent that you run, you can have a near infinite # of them, regardless of bootstap-expect settings.

Comment: I got the config file location and it worked. File looked a bit different (all config weren't there.)